# What is the type of a pointer to a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, multidimensional-array

I know that the following is not correct:

```
int arr[2][3] = {}; //some array initialization here
int** ptr;
ptr = arr;
```

But I am quite surprised that the following lines actually work

```
int arr[2][3] = {}; //some array initialization here
auto ptr = arr;
int another_arr[2][3] = {}; //some array initialization here
ptr = another_arr;
```

Can anyone possibly explain what is the type assigned to ptr in the second  block of code, and what happened underneath?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, arrays decay to pointers when used practically everywhere. So naturally there's decay going on in your code snippet too.

But it's only the "outer-most" array dimension that decays to a pointer. Since arrays are row-major, you end up with `int (*)[3]` as the pointer type, which is a pointer to a one-dimensional array, not a two dimensional array. It points to the first "row".

If you want `ptr`'s deduction to be a pointer *to the array* instead, then use the address-of operator:

```
auto ptr = &arr;
```

Now `ptr` is `int(*)[2][3]`.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how should I declare the type of `ptr` at the beginning if I do not use the keyword `auto`? Thanks.

Comment: @R.Xin - With the slightly convoluted syntax `int (* ptr )[3] = arr;` Most people will typedef that if they need to repeat such declarations often.

Comment: @R.Xin if you want to use a typedef like StoryTeller suggests, I recommend `typedef int MyArr[3]; MyArr* ptr;`

Comment: @user2079303 - Great point about the evils of hiding pointer semantics!

Comment: @StoryTeller I fixed the comment, thanks. The fact that the array size is detached from the type is counter intuitive to me. I think `using MyArr = int[3]` would be better.

Answer (score 12):

In

```
auto ptr = arr;
```

`arr` decays into a pointer to its first element in the normal way; it's equivalent to

```
auto ptr = &arr[0];
```

Since `arr[0]` is an array of three `int`s, that makes `ptr` a `int (*)[3]` - a pointer to `int[3]`.

`another_arr` decays in exactly the same way, so in

```
ptr = another_arr;
```

both sides of the assignment have the type `int (*)[3]`, and you can assign a `T*` to a `T*` for any type `T`.

A pointer to `arr` itself has type `int(*)[2][3]`.

If you want a pointer to the array rather than a pointer to the array's first element, you need to use `&`:

```
auto ptr = &arr;
```

Answer (score 7):

First, let's look at why you can't assign `int arr[2][3]` to `int **`. To make it easier to visualise, we'll initialise your array with a sequence, and consider what it looks like in memory:

```
int arr[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

In memory, the array data is stored as a single block, just like a regular, 1D array:

```
arr: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

The variable `arr` contains the address of the start of this block, and from its type (`int[2][3]`) the compiler knows to interpret an index like `arr[1][0]` as meaning "take the value that is at position (1*2 + 0) in the array".

However for a pointer-to-pointer (`int**`), it is expected that the pointer-to-pointer contains either a single memory address or an array of memory addresses, and this/these adress(es) point to (an)other single int value or array of ints. Let's say we copied the array `arr` into `int **ptrptr`. In memory, it would look like this:

```
ptrptr:     [0x203F0B20, 0x203F17D4]
0x203F0B20: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
0x203F17D4: [ 4, 5, 6 ]
```

So in addition to the actual `int` data, an extra pointer must be stored for each row of the array. Rather than converting the two indexes into a single array lookup, access must be performed by making a first array lookup ("take the second value in ptrptr to get an int*"), then nother array lookup ("take the first value in the array at the address held by the previously obtained int*").

Here's a program that illustrates this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int arr[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};

    std::cout << "Memory addresses for int arr[2][3]:" << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            std::cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&arr[i][j]) << ": " << arr[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "Memory addresses for int **ptrptr:" << std::endl;
    int **ptrptr = new int*[2];
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        ptrptr[i] = new int[3];
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            ptrptr[i][j] = arr[i][j];
            std::cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&ptrptr[i][j]) << ": " << ptrptr[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // Cleanup
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        delete[] ptrptr[i];
        ptrptr[i] = nullptr;
    }
    delete[] ptrptr;
    ptrptr = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Memory addresses for int arr[2][3]:
0x7ecd3ccc0260: 1
0x7ecd3ccc0264: 2
0x7ecd3ccc0268: 3
0x7ecd3ccc026c: 4
0x7ecd3ccc0270: 5
0x7ecd3ccc0274: 6

Memory addresses for int **ptrptr:
0x38a1a70: 1
0x38a1a74: 2
0x38a1a78: 3
0x38a1a90: 4
0x38a1a94: 5
0x38a1a98: 6
```

Notice how the memory addresses always increase by 4 bytes for `arr`, but for `ptrptr` there is a jump of 24 bytes between values 3 and 4.

A simple assignment can't create the pointer-to-pointer structure needed for type `int **`, which is why the loops were necessary in the above program. The best it can do is to decay the `int[2][3]` type into a pointer to a row of that array, i.e. `int (*)[3]`. That's what your `auto ptr = arr;` ends up as.

Comment: Ah, only now I see that you already show the iniatialisation of arr's memory, great to see this in-depth explanation :-)

Answer (score 3):

> What is the type of [...]

Did you already try to ask the compiler to tell you the type of an expression?

```
int main()
{
    int arr[2][3] = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}};  // <-- direct complete initialized here

    auto ptr = arr;                     // <-- address assignment only

    cout << "arr: " << typeid(arr).name() << endl;
    cout << "ptr: " << typeid(ptr).name() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've to confess that the output

```
arr: A2_A3_i
ptr: PA3_i
```

seems to be not very readable at first glance (compared to some other languages), but when in doubt it may help. It's very compact, but one may get used to it soon. The encoding is compiler-dependent, in case you are using gcc, you may read  [Chapter 29. Demangling](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) to understand how.

### Edit:

some experimentation with some `simple_cpp_name` function like this rudimentary hack

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

std::string simple_cpp_name(const std::type_info& ti)
{
    /// simplified code extracted from "Chapter 29. Demangling"
    /// https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html
    char* realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(ti.name(), 0, 0, 0);
    std::string name = realname;
    free(realname);
    return name;
}
```

will show you that `auto &rfa = arr;` makes `rfa` having the same type as `arr` which is `int [2][3]`.

Comment: Yes, I did try this, but I failed to understand the run-time specific code.

Comment: @R.Xin After all, the fact that the `auto ptr` is on indirection level apart from the original declaration as [pointed out by StorryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45409805/2932052) seems to be easy to see.